# Pasar de una página a otra en ReactJS sin usar React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

Estoy construyendo la página de LogIn de una web y cuando el usuario introduce email y contraseña y le da a la tecla "Enter" del teclado, me gustaría que eso saltase a la página /Home, por ejemplo.

Hasta ahora, lo que hacía para pasar entre páginas era usar el Link de React Router, pero eso ya no me funciona ya que el usuario no hace click en ninguna parte.

Gracias

Comment: Quizás podría servirte esta respuesta, comenta si es que no para ver otra manera de ayudarte ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827234/how-to-handle-the-onkeypress-event-in-reactjs

Comment: @MauricioRoss eso es lo que estoy utilizando, de hecho cuando el usuario le da a Enter salta un alert. Pero he intentado meter un Link de React Router y no me funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya tienes instalado el paquete `react-router-dom` en tu proyecto, simplemente utiliza el HOC `withRouter` sobre el componente que necesites hacer el cambio de página.

Con esto tendrás acceso al historial de tu aplicación y podrás utilizar `history.push('/home')` para navegar a la ruta que necesitas.

Por ejemplo:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const Login = (props) => {
    const { history } = props

    const handleLogin = () => {
        ...

        history.push('/home')
    }

    return (
        <>...</>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Login)
```

El botón `submit` de tu formulario debería llamar a la función `handleLogin()` y tendrías que controlar los eventos `enter` sobre los campos de texto, que también llamarían a esa función.

Comment: Esto ha funcionado perfectamente. Muchas gracias!